# Merge sorting an array then adding

Tags: sorting, merge

I finally got my program to sort my array but I cannot get it to add it. I am getting an error that reads:

`MergeSorter.java:21: error: non-static method sumOfArray(int[],int) cannot be referenced from a static context`

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSorter{ 
   public static void sort(int[] a)
   {  
      if (a.length <= 1) { return; }
      int[] first = new int[a.length / 2];
      int[] second = new int[a.length - first.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) 
      { 
         first[i] = a[i]; 
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < second.length; i++) 
      { 
         second[i] = a[first.length + i]; 
      }
      sort(first);
      sort(second);
      merge(first, second, a);
      int sum =sumOfArray(a, a.length-1); 
   }

 private static void merge(int[] first, int[] second, int[] a){         
     int iFirst = 0; 
      int iSecond = 0;
      int j = 0; 
      while (iFirst < first.length && iSecond < second.length){  
         if (first[iFirst] < second[iSecond]) {  
            a[j] = first[iFirst];
            iFirst++;
         }
         else{  
            a[j] = second[iSecond];
            iSecond++;
         }
         j++;
      }
      while (iFirst < first.length){ 
         a[j] = first[iFirst]; 
         iFirst++; j++;
      }
      while (iSecond < second.length){ 
         a[j] = second[iSecond]; 
         iSecond++; j++;
      }
   }

   public int sumOfArray(int[] a, int n){
    if (n == 0)
        return a[n];
    else
        return a[n] + sumOfArray(a, n-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I feel so dumb! I have been staring at this all night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it static?
like :

```
public static int sumOfArray(int[] a, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return a[n];
    else
        return a[n] + sumOfArray(a, n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)

In short, you need to make the method static, or call it on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to change

```
 public int sumOfArray(int[] a, int n)
```

to

```
 public static int sumOfArray(int[] a, int n)
```

otherwise you would have to create a MergeSorter object and call the sumOfArray method:

```
 int sum =new MergeSorter().sumOfArray(a, a.length-1)
```